# Running Dockerized applications to transform local files with unknown names

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working on Dockerizing a suite of Ruby apps stored on a server. The majority of these apps are used to edit local files (various zip and HTML files) on the user's computer. This is the general workflow:

1. User adds loose files to a working folder. These are the files they will be working on.
2. User launches an applet stored in the same working folder as the files. The applet executes the main accessor Ruby app, which opens a Terminal window and prints a list (from a YAML file) of all the available Ruby apps.
3. User selects the name of the app they want to run. The app is executed in the working folder, on the files in that folder.
4. User closes Terminal when they're done.

The filenames are not known but the extensions are, so the apps use Ruby's directory class with a wildcard to iterate over whatever files are in the folder: `Dir.glob("*.{file extension]")`.

I've made a Docker image for the applications, which is meant to work in the same way. I'm not sure that this is the most efficient workflow now that I'm using Docker, but in any case, this is my simplified Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5

RUN mkdir /applications 
WORKDIR /applications

COPY Gemfile /applications/ 
COPY Gemfile.lock /applications/ 

RUN bundle install

COPY . /app_src

ENTRYPOINT ruby main.rb    # the main accessor app that prints the list of apps
```

and my docker-compose file (with a mounted volume so I can more easily work in development mode):

```
version: '3'

services:
  script_library:
    build: ./app_src
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - './app_src:/applications'
```

Naturally, when testing things out, the apps work if I include working files in the `app_src` folder. In practice, of course, when I am building and running the image, I can't add the files I would want to run the apps on, because that's up to the user to select. The only option it seems would be to mount the files to a volume that the Docker container can then access, but all of the examples I've seen use absolute paths to do so.

To summarize, how do I make the Dockerized apps:

- run on the loose files in the local folder from which the user is running the apps,
- run on files without known filenames or absolute paths (the apps use relative paths to find and modify the files), and
- output new versions of the files in the same folder once the apps are done running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you have no choice but to use a bind mount here.  However, at a pure-Docker level, there's no specific requirement that you use the same path on the host and container side.

A typical setup for this is to pick some fixed path inside the container and treat that as part of the external interface of the container.  There are a couple of ways to manage this; probably the best is to make the script take the path name as a parameter

```sh
# Copy the application source into the same place as the Gemfile
# (This is a correction from the original Dockerfile)
COPY . /application

# When the container is launched, explicitly pass an alternate
# directory /data as a command-line parameter
# (Use JSON-array form for ENTRYPOINT so that additional parameters
# passed in CMD don't get swallowed)
ENTRYPOINT ["ruby", "/application/main.rb", "/data"]
```

And then pass the bind mount when you run it

```sh
docker run      \
  --rm          \  # delete the container on exit
  -it           \  # accept interactive input
  -v $PWD:/data \  # mount current directory on /data
  -u $(id -u)   \  # run as host user ID
  myscript         # image name
                   # do not bind mount content over the image code
```

Even with this there are a number of things the container can't do, like launch a new Terminal window.  Similarly, Docker Compose is generally oriented towards running multiple long-running containers in parallel, and it may not work well to just `docker-compose up` the file you show.  (I'd expect `docker-compose run script_library` to work.)

Note here that you're spending a lot of effort to work around Docker's filesystem isolation, and there are still significant security concerns (what happens if you use `-u root -v /etc:/data`?).  For tools whose main goal is to read and write local files, Docker tends to not be a great fit as a packaging mechanism.  This is doubly true if the script is in the same directory as the files you're working on, as you describe in the question; it's easier to just install Ruby and run `ruby main.rb`.

Comment: This is immensely helpful. The last part of what you said is exactly what I've been struggling with. Installing/updating Ruby on the end users' computers has resulted in time-consuming issues over the years, so I was trying to find a way to package the required Ruby environment. I was exploring Docker as a potential solution given its ubiquity and robustness, and I wasn't sure if I was just missing some essential knowledge or if it's just not the right option for my project. Sadly, it doesn't seem like there are many up-to-date alternatives for packaging Ruby apps. :( Thank you for your help!